# Reduce Load Time of image in ImageView in Android

Tags: android, imageview

I have a `ImageView` And a button and 2 images .  Clicking the button causes toggling the images in `ImageView`.

**Here is the code**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this );

        flag = true; 
        imageView1 = (ImageView ) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.off);

    } 

    @Override
    public void onClick(View  v) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //  imageView1.setImageResource(R.id.);
        //imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.off_widget);
          flag= !flag;
        if( flag == true  )
        {
            imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.off);
        }
        else
        {
            imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.on);
        }
```

But the load time is huge . The size of the image is 188 KB and 110 KB . What can I do to reduce load time ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is not the loading time, even 200KB image is not that big. Your GUI actually freezes for a short time (the time needed for loading the image) caused by the loading of the image. This causes the toggling.

The best practice here to prevent the GUI from freezing is loading the image in an `AsyncTask` as an `Drawable` and afterward assign it to the `ImageView`. You can find an code example [here](http://briandolhansky.com/blog/2013/7/11/snippets-android-async-progress). You just invoke the task from your `onCreate(...)` or `onStart(...)`. Another best practice for geeting the `Drawable` from the `AsyncTask` to you main Activity is using the [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), where your `AsyncTask` is the [Observer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Observer.html) and your main Activity is the Observable. Android already provides prober classes for this. You can also find an code example [here](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/08/implementing-loaders.html).

Comment: `AsyncTask` class allows us to perform long/background operations and show its result on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads.

Comment: according to me it doesn't make any sense to use `AsyncTast` for the above question.

Comment: I get your intention. This is of course a lot of code and one could think that there must be a shorter solution to this, I agree. But the problem (which causes the toggling) still is that the GUI freezes and to prevent this the only solution is to load the image not in the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you store the off and on images? Did you create a scaled version for each screen density?

When you add a 100kb image to the drawable directory (instead of drawable-) the image will be treated as a mdpi image and therefore scaled to the density of your device. So a png in the drawable directory takes a lot more memory on a xxhdpi device than 100kb.